# How to upload files to azure blob storage?

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage, azcopy

I need to upload files to azure blob container every day from local system. I use azcopy with sas for doing it.
But what i encountered is that SAS for container keep changing on every refresh.
So is there any better way i can upload files using python or azcopy.
Or is there any way to get the SAS toke from the azure without login and pass that SAS token to azcopy command?
as of now i use this command from azcopy

```
.\azcopy "Sourcefilepath" "Destblobpath?SAS_Token" --recurcive=true
```

Each day i should login to azure get the SAS token and pass for the above command. 
i tried .\azcopy login and i get login successful, but i cant send files with

```
.\azcopy "Sourcepath" "Destpath"
```

Don't know where i'm doing wrong.

Comment: Not sure I understand: Why are you logging in (and what are you logging into?) to get a SAS every day? Is it the same container every day? If so, why not just generate a SAS that has an extended lifetime?

Comment: I upload files to azure blob everyday. this i'm doing by going through azure portal and locating the container and upload files to it. Rather i thought of sending the files using azcopy. The problem i'm facing is the sas keep changing each time there is a refresh or some timeout i dont know.  So how to achieve this task of uploading files from local to blob using sas or without sas token. you mentioned about getting extended token that has lifetime, How can i get this? Yes the container is same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using python, I would suggest using the azure python sdk to do your uploading.  You can see more from this example here...

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/storage-blobs-python-quickstart/blob/master/example.py

It can be as quick as this (from the quick start docs : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/overview/azure/storage?view=azure-python) to interface with your azure blob storage account.  Just put in some logic to loop through a directory recursively and upload each file.

First make sure to pip install the required packages, and then grab your account name (blob storage name) and your access key from the portal...plug them in and you're good to go.

```
pip install azure-storage-blob azure-mgmt-storage
```

Then write some python code here...

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService, PublicAccess

blob_service = BlockBlobService('[your account name]','[your access key]')

blob_service.create_container(
    'mycontainername',
    public_access=PublicAccess.Blob
)

blob_service.create_blob_from_bytes(
    'mycontainername',
    'myblobname',
    b'hello from my python file'
)

print(blob_service.make_blob_url('mycontainername', 'myblobname'))
```

This should get you going in the right direction pretty quickly.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're seeing for SAS is actually working as it's supposed to. SAS has an expiration date, and can be revoked at anytime you want. So you'll be required to use the new one as soon as it is available.

I'd recommend using the python SDK since it uses the Storage Key and Account name, which doesn't expire, except when a key is rotated. I wrote a few tools/Samples in python SDK which performs all actions: List, Upload and delete: **https://github.com/adamsmith0016/Azure-storage**

Feel free to clone and re-use any code.

Comment: Thankd for the answer..Does your code uploads all the files in the folder specified? I have some 6 files in the local folder and  want to upload all of them without any prompt for yes or no! And i need to delete only one particular file containing timestamp of yesterdays date like filename-24MAR2019. Can i achieve all this without need for user input. I know its a dumb question!

Comment: You can definitely do it without prompts  by editing the script :), you can also add precise regex to look for specific file extensions etc..